# how to get price with ebay API

Tags: php, debugging, ebay-api

So I have this code, but the price of the item isn't showing up.  Everything else (photo and link) is working.  I tried 'currentPrice' but nothing shows up. And this is the Ebay API. I spent about two hours looking for a solution, but it's not very well documented.

```
<?php
$endpoint  = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1'; // URL to call
$version   = '1.11.0'; // API version supported by your application
$appid     = 'myid'; // Replace with your own AppID
$globalid  = 'EBAY-US'; // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
$query     = 'golf'; // You may want to supply your own query
$safequery = urlencode($query); // Make the query URL-friendly

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call
$apicall = "$endpoint?";
$apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced";
$apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
$apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
$apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
$apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
$apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=12";
$apicall .= "&paginationInput.pageNumber=1";
$apicall .= "&categoryId=1513";

// Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
$resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

// Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
    $results = '';
    // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
    foreach ($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
        $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
        $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
        $title = $item->title;
        $price = $item->currentPrice;

        // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
        $results .= "<div id='prod-wrap'><div class='prodimg-wrap' align='center'><img src=\"$pic\" class='prodimg'></div> <div class='prodtxt' align='center'><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></div><div class='price' align='center'><p class='price' align='center'>$price</p></div></div>";
    }
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
    $results = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
    $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}
?>
<!-- Build the HTML page with values from the call response -->
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        }

        img {
            border: none;
        }

        #store-wrap {
            width:    770px;
            height:   auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        #filter-wrap {
            width:            160px;
            float:            left;
            height:           500px;
            margin-right:     10px;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
        }

        #result-wrap {
            width:    600px;
            float:    left;
            height:   auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        #pagination-wrap {
            width:  200px;
            float:  right;
            height: 20px;
        }

        #prod-wrap {
            width:            150px;
            height:           200px;
            margin:           0 15px 15px;
            float:            left;
            border:           1px solid #999999;
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }

        .prodimg-wrap {
            width: 150px;
        }

        .prodimg {
            width:   100px;
            height:  100px;
            padding: 4px;
        }

        .prodtxt {
            font-size: 11px;
            width:     130px;
            padding:   0 8px;
        }
        .price {
            font-size: 11px;
            width: 60px;
            padding: 0 8px;
        }
        .price p {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $query; ?></h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="store-wrap">

                <div id="result-wrap">
                    <?php echo $results;?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($item)` inside your loop?

Comment: @andrewsi I think this line is interesting when I do that:  ["sellingStatus"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (5) { ["currentPrice"]=> string(5) "34.99"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it with   `findItemsAdvanced.searchResult.item.sellingStatus`

```
 $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
```

`searchResult.item.sellingStatus.currentPrice   Amount (double)`

The current price of the item given in the currency of the site on which the item is listed. That is, currentPrice is returned in the original listing currency.

For competitive-bid item listings, currentPrice is the current minimum bid price if the listing has no bids, or the current high bid if the listing has bids. A Buy It Now price has no effect on currentPrice.

For Basic Fixed-Price (FixedPrice), Store Inventory (StoreInventory), Ad Format (AdFormat), and Classified Ad (Classified) listings, currentPrice is the current fixed price.

Comment: Could you please explain where this is added in the sample code?